# How to run command-line SQLite query and exit?

Tags: sqlite, shell, command-line

When I use the `-cmd` option with SQLite3 to run a query SQLite3 opens the database and waits for interactive input. How can I run a query on SQLite3 from the command line and exit?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Just include the command in quotes after the database file argument.

For example, the following creates a table called `abc`:

```
sqlite3 test.db 'create table abc (col0 int)'
```

Answer (score 55):

You can use the `.exit` command ([1](https://sqlite.org/cli.html)), to exit gracefully:

```
sqlite3 test.db "select * from abc;" ".exit"
```

Documentation: [Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/cli.html).

Comment: +1: This was useful for enabling headers and setting the mode: `sqlite3 db.sqlite3 ".headers on" ".mode column" "select * from auth_user;" | less -S -#10`!

Comment: You can also set mode by using command line arguments as well: `sqlite3 -box my.db "select * from table;"`. Type `sqlite3 --help` to see other options.

Comment: The link to the sqlite docs help to get an idea of the commands - but it does not help to write commands without being in the sqlite env. So I would add that.

Comment: What's the advantage of using `.exit` here? Tested as of 3.40.1, `sqlite3 test.db "select * from abc;"` works just fine and then exits gracefully.

Comment: `.exit` is redundant.

Comment: It's not redundant for some commands (`-init`, e.g.) Without .exit, the CLI waits indefinitely.

Answer (score 6):

If you are stuck in a situation where you absolutely "have to" use the `-cmd` flag when you are running SQLite 3 from the command line, you can use successive *blank* command to exit.

For example:

```
sqlite3 test.db "select * from urls;" "" > test.txt
```

In this example, the `""` will cause the SQLite 3 process to exit. (At least it does for me on OS X.)

Answer (score 5):

Also it might be useful to have multiline queries:

```sh
sqlite3 ./database.db <<EOF
    SELECT *
    FROM something
    LIMIT 5
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

**The general command syntax**

This was confusing me a bit partly because `man sqlite3` uses a weird notation so here goes, the syntax in more common GNU-like notation is:

```
sqlite3 [opt]... [<db> [sql]...]
```

This means that the first argument that starts without a dash `-` has to be the database name.

And then, every other argument is a separate SQL statement that happens on that database.

Some valid example commands:

```
sqlite3 
sqlite3 db.sqlite3
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 "select * from t"
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 "select col1 from t" "select col2 from t"
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 "select col1 from t; select col2 from t"
sqlite3 -line
sqlite3 -line db.sqlite3
sqlite3 -line db.sqlite3 "select * from t"
sqlite3 -line db.sqlite3 "select col1 from t" "select col2 from t"
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 ".schema"
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 ".schema" "select * from t"
```

**If there is one or more positional `sql` commands, then there is no interactive shell at the end**

Therefore the following exit without interactive shell:

- `sqlite3 db.sqlite3 "select col1 from t"`: one SQL statement
- `sqlite3 db.sqlite3 "select col1 from t" "select col2 from t"`: two SQL statements
- `sqlite3 db.sqlite3 ".schema"`: one SQL statement
- `sqlite3 db.sqlite3 ".schema" "select col1 from t"`: two SQL statements

but the following open an interactive shell because they have no positional SQL commands:

```
sqlite3
sqlite3 -cmd "select col1 from t" -cmd "select col2 from t" db.sqlite3
```

So we see that what `-cmd` does is to allow running a SQL statement while still getting an interactive shell at the end.

**If commands come from non interactive stdin (e.g. pipe), then there is also no interactive shell at the end**

E.g. this exits immediately:

```
echo 'select 1' | sqlite3
```

**To run a query without a DB and exit you can use the magic `:memory:` temporary in-memory database**

E.g. this can be useful for quick function testing:

```
sqlite3 ':memory:' 'select 1 + 1'
```

And if you really want to show off you can also use that with a CTE to show off your `SELECT` skills with single statements:

```
sqlite3 ':memory:' 'WITH t (i, j) AS (VALUES (1, -1), (2, -2)) SELECT * FROM t'
```

**`-cmd` is only needed when you want to run a command before stdin**

E.g. a common use case for me is to `.mode csv` before running a large command from stdin via Bash EOF e.g.:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 -cmd '.mode csv' <<EOF
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM t
  )
)
EOF
```

This form is useful because dot `.` commands like `.mode` don't seem to be allowed from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the question, we can also make use of the '-cmd' option and... apply some shell 'magic' at the end (to imitate user manual 'exit'). Let's evaluate a sql expression:

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 -cmd "select 5.0/2;" < `echo ".exit"`

2.5
```

This approach is effective, when we have to submit '.xxx' sqlite meta-commands (i.e. .show or .stat) as well:

```
sqlite3 -cmd ".stat" < `echo ".exit"`

Memory Used:                         0 (max 56) bytes
Number of Outstanding Allocations:   0 (max 2)
Number of Pcache Overflow Bytes:     0 (max 0) bytes
Largest Allocation:                  40 bytes
Largest Pcache Allocation:           0 bytes
Bytes received by read():            10992
Bytes sent to write():               253
Read() system calls:                 19
Write() system calls:                6
Bytes read from storage:             0
Bytes written to storage:            0
Cancelled write bytes:               0
```

Note: Tested in dash & bash. Should also play in zsh, fish, etc.

Comment: You say you tested it but bash complains about `bash: .exit: no such file or directory` and rightfully so.

Answer (score 0):

There are queries and there are [dot-commands](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#special_commands_to_sqlite3_dot_commands_).

What can we pass to `sqlite3`? Let us check.

```
% sqlite3 --help
Usage: sqlite3 [OPTIONS] FILENAME [SQL]
```

We can also use dot-commands in place of `[SQL]`. However, there might be some exceptions which i am not aware about.

To list all dot-commands,run:

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite .help
```

Here, `test.sqlite` is the `FILENAME`.

To view the schema of the database, run:

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite .schema
```

To list all tables of the database, run:

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite .tables
```

If you must use `-cmd` then the command will look like:

```
sqlite3 -cmd .tables test.sqlite .quit
```

Now you can run query on the databases using:

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite "select * from DATABASE_NAME"
```

If you must use `-cmd` then the command will look like:

```
sqlite3 -cmd "select * from object_store" test.sqlite .quit
```

You might have already noticed, when using `-cmd` we are using more than one commands. Yes, we can do something like:

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite ".print The Tables Are:\n" ".tables" ".print \nThe Schema is:\n" ".schema" ".print \nList Of All Customers:\n" "select * from customers"
```

If you must use `-cmd` then the command will look like:

```
sqlite3 -cmd ".print The Tables Are:\n" -cmd ".tables" -cmd ".print \nThe Schema is:\n" -cmd ".schema" -cmd ".print \nList Of All Customers:\n" -cmd "select * from object_store" test.sqlite .quit
```

**NOTE:** From previous examples, we can see that, we only need to use `.quit` or `.exit`, if you use `-cmd`. Otherwise, it is not needed.

Answer (score -1):

**This command below** inserts a row to **`person` table**, then reads **`person` table** in **`db.sqlite3` database** then exits at once. ***`".exit"` command** is not needed to exit because after all queries complete, **sqlite** automatically exits:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 "INSERT INTO person VALUES ('John');" "SELECT * FROM person;"
```